# How to do join of multiindex dataframe with a single index dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

The single index of df1 matches with a sublevel of multiindex of df2. Both have the same columns. I want to copy all rows and columns of df1 to df2.

It is similar to this thread:
[copying a single-index DataFrame into a MultiIndex DataFrame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17451843/copying-a-single-index-dataframe-into-a-multiindex-dataframe)

But that solution only work for one index value, the index 'a' in that case. I want to do this operation for all index of df1.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: import itertools
In [4]: inner = ('a','b')
In [5]: outer = ((10,20), (1,2))
In [6]: cols = ('one','two','three','four')
In [7]: sngl = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,4), index=inner, columns=cols)
In [8]: index_tups = list(itertools.product(*(outer + (inner,))))
In [9]: index_mult = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_tups)
In [10]: mult = pd.DataFrame(index=index_mult, columns=cols)
In [11]: sngl
Out[11]: 
        one       two     three      four
a  2.946876 -0.751171  2.306766  0.323146
b  0.192558  0.928031  1.230475 -0.256739

In [12]: mult
Out[12]: 
        one  two three four
10 1 a  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
     b  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
   2 a  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
     b  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
20 1 a  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
     b  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
   2 a  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
     b  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN


In [13]: mult.ix[(10,1)] = sngl

In [14]: mult
Out[14]: 
        one  two three four
10 1 a  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
     b  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
   2 a  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
     b  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
20 1 a  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
     b  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
   2 a  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
     b  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
```

The solution given by @Jeff is

```
nm = mult.reset_index().set_index('level_2')
nm.loc['a',sngl.columns] = sngl.loc['a'].values

         level_0  level_1        one        two     three        four
level_2                                                              
a             10        1  0.3738456 -0.2261926 -1.205177  0.08448757
b             10        1        NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN
a             10        2  0.3738456 -0.2261926 -1.205177  0.08448757
b             10        2        NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN
a             20        1  0.3738456 -0.2261926 -1.205177  0.08448757
b             20        1        NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN
a             20        2  0.3738456 -0.2261926 -1.205177  0.08448757
b             20        2        NaN        NaN       NaN         NaN
```

I can't do this:

```
nm.loc[:,sngl.columns] = sngl.loc[:].values
```

It will raise ValueError: "cannot copy sequence with size X to array axis with dimension Y"

I am currently using a loop. But this is not the pandas way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This feels a little too manual, but in practice I might do something like this:

```
In [46]: mult[:] = sngl.loc[mult.index.get_level_values(2)].values

In [47]: mult
Out[47]: 
             one       two     three      four
10 1 a  1.175042  0.044014  1.341404 -0.223872
     b  0.216168 -0.748194 -0.546003 -0.501149
   2 a  1.175042  0.044014  1.341404 -0.223872
     b  0.216168 -0.748194 -0.546003 -0.501149
20 1 a  1.175042  0.044014  1.341404 -0.223872
     b  0.216168 -0.748194 -0.546003 -0.501149
   2 a  1.175042  0.044014  1.341404 -0.223872
     b  0.216168 -0.748194 -0.546003 -0.501149
```

That is, first select the elements we want to use to index:

```
In [64]: mult.index.get_level_values(2)
Out[64]: Index(['a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'b'], dtype='object')
```

Then use these to index into `sngl`:

```
In [65]: sngl.loc[mult.index.get_level_values(2)]
Out[65]: 
        one       two     three      four
a  1.175042  0.044014  1.341404 -0.223872
b  0.216168 -0.748194 -0.546003 -0.501149
a  1.175042  0.044014  1.341404 -0.223872
b  0.216168 -0.748194 -0.546003 -0.501149
a  1.175042  0.044014  1.341404 -0.223872
b  0.216168 -0.748194 -0.546003 -0.501149
a  1.175042  0.044014  1.341404 -0.223872
b  0.216168 -0.748194 -0.546003 -0.501149
```

and then we can use `.values` to throw away the indexing information and just get the raw array to fill with.

It's not very elegant, but it's straightforward.

Comment: cool! What if add an additional hierarchical index to both sng1 and mult? mult.index.get_level_values(2) can only work for one level.  sng2=pd.concat([sng1,sng1],keys=['X','Y']), 
    mult2=pd.concat([mult,mult],keys=['X','Y']). To make this thread clear, I posted a new one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32748910/how-to-do-join-of-multiindex-dataframe-with-another-multiindex-dataframe