# How to do join of multiindex dataframe with another multiindex dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

This is to go further from the following thread:
[How to do join of multiindex dataframe with a single index dataframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747772/how-to-do-join-of-multiindex-dataframe-with-a-single-index-dataframe)

The multi-indices of df1 are sublevel indices of df2.

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd
In [2]: import numpy as np
In [3]: import itertools
In [4]: inner = ('a','b')
In [5]: outer = ((10,20), (1,2))
In [6]: cols = ('one','two','three','four')
In [7]: sngl = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(2,4), index=inner, columns=cols)
In [8]: index_tups = list(itertools.product(*(outer + (inner,))))
In [9]: index_mult = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(index_tups)
In [10]: mult = pd.DataFrame(index=index_mult, columns=cols)
In [11]: sngl
Out[11]: 
        one       two     three      four
a  2.946876 -0.751171  2.306766  0.323146
b  0.192558  0.928031  1.230475 -0.256739

In [12]: mult
Out[12]: 
        one  two three four
10 1 a  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
     b  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
   2 a  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
     b  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
20 1 a  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
     b  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
   2 a  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
     b  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN


In [13]: mult.ix[(10,1)] = sngl

In [14]: mult
Out[14]: 
        one  two three four
10 1 a  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
     b  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
   2 a  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
     b  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
20 1 a  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
     b  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
   2 a  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN
     b  NaN  NaN   NaN  NaN

# the new dataframes
sng2=pd.concat([sng1,sng1],keys=['X','Y'])
mult2=pd.concat([mult,mult],keys=['X','Y'])

In [110]:

sng2
Out[110]:
             one     two           three    four
X   a   0.206810    -1.056264   -0.572809   -0.314475
    b   0.514873    -0.941380   0.132694    -0.682903
Y   a   0.206810    -1.056264   -0.572809   -0.314475
    b   0.514873    -0.941380   0.132694    -0.682903

In [121]: mult2
Out[121]:
               one  two three   four
X   10  1   a   NaN NaN NaN NaN
            b   NaN NaN NaN NaN
        2   a   NaN NaN NaN NaN
            b   NaN NaN NaN NaN
    20  1   a   NaN NaN NaN NaN
            b   NaN NaN NaN NaN
        2   a   NaN NaN NaN NaN
            b   NaN NaN NaN NaN
Y   10  1   a   NaN NaN NaN NaN
            b   NaN NaN NaN NaN
        2   a   NaN NaN NaN NaN
            b   NaN NaN NaN NaN
    20  1   a   NaN NaN NaN NaN
            b   NaN NaN NaN NaN
        2   a   NaN NaN NaN NaN
            b   NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

*the code above is long, please scroll*
The two multilevel indices of sng2 share the 1st and 4th indices of mul2. ('X','a') for example.

@DSM proposed a solution to work with a multiindex df2 and single index df1

```
mult[:] = sngl.loc[mult.index.get_level_values(2)].values
```

BUt DataFrame.index.get_level_values(2) can only work for one level of index.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not clear from the question which index levels the data frames share. I think you need to revise the set-up code as it gives an error at the definition of `sngl`. Anyway, suppose `mult` shares the first and second level with `sngl` you can just drop the second level from the index of `mult` and index in:

```
mult[:] = sngl.loc[mult.index.droplevel(2)].values
```

On a side note, you can construct a multi index from a product directly using `pd.MultiIndex.from_product` rather than using `itertools`