# How to join pandas dataframes which have a multiindex

Tags: pandas

#### Problem Description

I have a dataframe with a multi-index that is three levels deep (0, 1, 2) and I'd like to join this dataframe with another dataframe which is indexed by level 2 of my original dataframe.

In code, I'd like to turn:

```
pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).transpose().set_index([0, 1, 2])
```

and

```
pd.DataFrame(['c', 'e']).transpose().set_index(0)
```

into

```
pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']).transpose().set_index([0, 1, 2])
```

#### What I've tried

- I've tried using [swaplevel](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.swaplevel.html) and then [join](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.join.html#pandas.DataFrame.join). Didn't work, though some of the error messages suggested that if only I could set `on` properly this might work.
- I tried [concat](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html), but couldn't get this to work either. Not sure it can't work though...

#### Notes:

I have seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32747772/how-to-do-join-of-multiindex-dataframe-with-a-single-index-dataframe) in which the answer seems to dodge the question (while solving the problem).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`pandas` will naturally do this for you if the names of the index levels line up.  You can rename the index of the second dataframe and `join` accordingly.

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame(['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']).transpose().set_index([0, 1, 2])
d2 = pd.DataFrame(['c', 'e']).transpose().set_index(0)


d1.join(d2.rename_axis(2))

       3  1
0 1 2      
a b c  d  e
```

---

**More Comprehensive Example**

```
d1 = pd.DataFrame([
    [1, 2],
    [3, 4],
    [5, 6],
    [7, 8]
], pd.MultiIndex.from_product([['A', 'B'], ['X', 'Y']], names=['One', 'Two']))

d2 = pd.DataFrame([
    list('abcdefg')
], ['Y'], columns=list('ABCDEFG'))

d3 = pd.DataFrame([
    list('hij')
], ['A'], columns=list('HIJ'))

d1.join(d2.rename_axis('Two')).join(d3.rename_axis('One'))

         0  1    A    B    C    D    E    F    G    H    I    J
One Two                                                        
A   X    1  2  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN    h    i    j
    Y    3  4    a    b    c    d    e    f    g    h    i    j
B   X    5  6  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN  NaN
    Y    7  8    a    b    c    d    e    f    g  NaN  NaN  NaN
```